# Ejes en gráficos de barras horizontales con ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

tengo un problema resulta que tengo un gráfico donde una de las variables es continua y la otra es discreta (Etiquetas), el lio es que la variable continua, varia solo entre los valores 280 y 400, y es solo en esa parte de la gráfica donde es posible interpretarla.

Me gustaría saber como fijar el eje continúo de la gráfica sin que se pierdan los valores (Que estan en el intervalo antes mencionado), debo precisar que para fines de interpretación requiero la grafica horizontal, es decir con las barras de izquierda a derecha y no vertical, donde ese problema si tiene algo de solución.

```
colores = factor(c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2), labels=c("Ext","Pat")) 
df <- data.frame(x = c('T','L','E','P','C','D','Phy','Di','Me','Bem','Pol'), y = c(336.92,360.17,344.92,337.75,364.50,335.17,347.17,327.83,332.63,364.20,334.37)) 

library(ggplot2) 

Grafico = ggplot(data=df, aes(x,y,fill=colores)) + 
            geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
            scale_x_discrete("Especie/Sustancia") + 
            coord_flip() + 
            geom_hline(yintercept = 370, color="red") + 
            scale_y_continuous("Longitud de onda (nm)",limits = c(0,400), breaks =c (300, 400, 0)) + 
            scale_fill_grey("Muestra", start = 0.1, end = 0.6)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El `geom_bar()` es un geometría muy particular, en este caso y en general, es mucho mejor ajustar los limites desde el sistema de coordenadas que estés usando, en tu caso [`coord_flip`()](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/coord_flip.html), es decir:

```
coord_flip(ylim=c(200,400))
```